# Is it possible to change the input[type=text] history?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

When you click on an **input[type=text]** field with **autocomplete=on** the browser shows hints of the previous inputs. I want to change the values of those hints to my own recommendation list. I could build that feature from scratch but I'm wondering if I could change the hint values to save time. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: The browser's history? Hardly. You'll have to look for a Javascript-based solution that brings a lookup of its own

Comment: I want to make a list when users clicks my search box. I was thinking if I can do it with the browsers built-in on click display history but just change the values to the values of my list. I could build it but I was wondering for this route. downvotes . . . downvotes everywhere!!!

Comment: You're looking for a combobox, something HTML4 doesn't support. HTML5 apparently does it, but I've never used it.

Comment: just search for an autocomplete jquery plugin on google, there are plenty that can do what you want

Comment: Check this out http://www.scriptol.com/html5/combobox.php

Comment: @Pekka웃 i like what i saw!!! its exactly what I need!!! thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" list="browserList" name="browser">
<datalist id="browserList">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zu4Ch/3/)